# XDocument in Settings

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq, settings

I am trying to hand enter an `XDocument` in the settings pane of VS2010 without success.  The type is `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`

The message I get is:

> Cannot be converted to an instance of type
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument'

Does anyone know a way around this?

ST

Answer (score 5):

You can't create an `XDocument` setting directly, because the `XDocument` class doesn't meet the [criteria](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) used by the Settings to determine if a type can be used:

> Application settings can be stored as any data type that is XML serializable or has a TypeConverter that implements ToString/FromString. The most common types are String, Integer, and Boolean, but you can also store values as Color, Object, or as a connection string.

`XDocument` provides a way to create an XML document by parsing a string, but it's not a constructor, it's the static `Load` method (which takes a `TextWriter`, not a string).  So it's not suited for use in the Settings.

But you can subclass it, and give the subclass a type converter.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy to subclass `XDocument` with a type converter.  First, create a subclass:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyXDocumentTypeConverter))]
public class MyXDocument : XDocument
{
}
```

That class uses this `TypeConverter`:

```
public class MyXDocumentTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return (sourceType == typeof (string));
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            MyXDocument d = new MyXDocument();
            d.Add(XDocument.Load(new StringReader((string) value)).Elements().First());
            return d;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Once you have this set up, you can write code like this:

```
MyXDocument d = "<foo/>";
```

and the string `<foo/>` will get passed into the type converter and parsed (via `Load`) into an `XDocument`, whose top-level element then gets added to the `MyXDocument`.  This is the same assignment that the auto-generated code in `Settings.Designer.cs` uses:

```
return ((global::XmlSettingsDemo.MyXDocument)(this["Setting"]));
```

Now you can go into your Settings dialog and create a setting of this type.  You can't navigate to the type in the Type dialog; you have to manually enter the full name of the type (`XmlSettingsDemo.MyXDocument` was the name of mine).

Comment: Thank you Robert for a most comprehensive and thoughtful answer.  This has enabledme to achieve what I set out to achieve - thank you once again!